# SFDX: source:push: CustomSite: Error: force-app\main\default\sites\site-name.site-meta.xml insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: salesforcedx, force.com-sites, scratch-org

I am trying to remove/delete a `CustomSite` from a Scratch Org.

I've done a `source:force:pull` to get the `metadata` onto my local machine, then I've deleted the `.site-meta.xml` file such that `source:force:status` returns:

```
STATE          FULL NAME   TYPE        PROJECT PATH
─────────────  ──────────  ──────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
Local Deleted  site        CustomSite  force-app\main\default\sites\site.site-meta.xml
```

But when I run:

```
source:force:push
```

I get error message:

```
TYPE   PROJECT PATH                                            PROBLEM
─────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  force-app\main\default\sites\site.site-meta.xml         insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed
```

Note: the site is `deactivated`.

**Question**

1. What is causing this error?
2. Is there a related record I need to delete before I can remove the site?
3. Is what I am doing even possible?

Comment: Check if a site/the site is deletable via the Setup UI. If not it is likely that delete is not possible. And if it is possible, you may get a clearer error explanation.

Comment: Hi @KeithC, thanks, there isn't a 'delete' button as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a force.com site is still not allowed, here is the relevant idea: [we should be able to delete force.com sites](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Zd7tAAC)